# Expand div without pushing div below

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, i have this code which expands the div height to show a hidden div with a transition.

The problem is that the div below is pushed when expanding the main div. I know position absolute or even relative can do it, but I can't figure out where exactly i have to put the code.

I've tried some things but none of them worked, i'll be grateful if anyone can help.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oab68y6t/3/)

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

.produtos-destaque {
  width: 200px;
  height: 71px;
  background: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  transition: height .2s ease;
}

.produtos-destaque:hover {
  height: 131px;
}

.titulo-produto-home {
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
}

.produtos-destaque h3 {
  height: 31px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(140, 140, 140);
  font-size: 13px;
}

.produtos-destaque:hover .btn-produto {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-produto {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.btn-comprar {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fbbe3f;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="produtos-destaque">
  <div class="titulo-produto-home">
    <a href="#">
      <h3>Produto produto produto produto produto</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-produto">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="btn-comprar">Comprar</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>I want this to not be pushed</div>
```

Comment: Is the height of the `.produtos-destaque` static or dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small update in CSS:

```
.produtos-destaque {
  width: 200px;
  height: 71px;
  background: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  transition: all .2s ease;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.produtos-destaque:hover {
  height: 131px;
  margin-bottom:-60px;
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

.produtos-destaque {
  width: 200px;
  height: 71px;
  background: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  transition: all .2s ease;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.produtos-destaque:hover {
  height: 131px;
  margin-bottom:-60px;
}

.titulo-produto-home {
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
}

.produtos-destaque h3 {
  height: 31px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(140, 140, 140);
  font-size: 13px;
}

.produtos-destaque:hover .btn-produto {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-produto {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.btn-comprar {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fbbe3f;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="produtos-destaque">
  <div class="titulo-produto-home">
    <a href="#">
      <h3>Produto produto produto produto produto</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-produto">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="btn-comprar">Comprar</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>I want this to not be pushed</div>
```